# Find where $f(x)=x^4-4x-2$ is strictly decreasing and where it is strictly increasing

Tags: calculus

I have found that $f'(x)=0$ at $x=1$. I'm not sure if I should use an open interval or a closed interval to say where the function is strictly increasing and where it is strictly decreasing. I have read different definitions on that, and some suggest that it should be $(-\text{inf},1]$ and $[1,\text{inf})$, and others suggest that it should be $(-\text{inf},1)$ and $(1,\text{inf})$. So, what is correct? I need it to show that the function at most has two roots.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I.e., find where $f'(x)<0$ and where $f'(x)>0$. I.e., find when $x^3<1$ (i.e. $x<1$) and when $x^3>1$ (i.e. $x>1$).

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x) = 4x^3-4 = 4(x^3-1) > 0 \iff x > 1 \iff \text{ f is stritcly increasing .I hope this helps}$.

Answer (score 0):

The general criterion is $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$, say, if $f′(x)>0$ on the open interval $(a,b)$. Hence, if $f′(x)>0$ on an interval, except on a discrete subset of $(a,b)$, $f$ is strictly increasing on the interval.

In the present case, $f$ is strictly increasing on the closed interval $[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you! So it is okay to say that f has a root in [-1,0] and a root in [1,2] because of what you said and the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: That's perfectly right.